# Simplify Rust extension trait lifetimes when using Add trait

Tags: rust, lifetime

I need an extension trait for everything that implements `AsRef<[T]>`. A method of this trait takes a reference to `T` and based on some math with it returns a sub-slice of the original array.

Sample code can look like:

```rust
trait Sample<T> {
    fn sample(&self, element: &T, k: usize) -> &[T];
}

impl<'a, A, T> Sample<T> for A
where
    A: AsRef<[T]>,
    &'a T: Add<Output = T>,
    T: 'a,
{
    fn sample(&self, element: &T, k: usize) -> &[T] {
        let array = self.as_ref();
        let doubled = element + element;
        &array[0..0]
    }
}
```

It does not compile, though.

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/arrays/sample.rs:15:23
   |
7  | impl<'a, A, T> Sample<T> for A
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
13 |     fn sample(&self, element: &T, k: usize) -> &[T] {
   |                               - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
14 |         let array = self.as_ref();
15 |         let doubled = element + element;
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ requires that `'1` must outlive `'a`
```

I don't really understand why `element` lifetime must be bigger than `'a`.

Anyways, after a while I made it work, but it does not feel right.

```rust
use core::ops::Add;

trait KClosestExt<'t, T> {
    fn find_k_closest(&'t self, element: &'t T, k: usize) -> &[T];
}

impl<'a, 't, A, T> KClosestExt<'t, T> for A
where
    A: AsRef<[T]>,
    &'a T: Add<Output = T>,
    T: 'a + 't + PartialOrd,
    't: 'a,
{
    fn find_k_closest(&'t self, element: &'t T, k: usize) -> &[T] {
        let array = self.as_ref();
        if k > array.len() {
            return array;
        }

        let doubled = element + element;
        let left = binary_search(0, array.len() - k, |mid| doubled > &array[mid + k] + &array[mid]);
        &array[left..left + k]
    }
}
```

According to what I need, is it possible to simplify lifetime management for this example?

Comment: Does the return value `&[T]` relies on the `element` argument in lifetime (i.e., `&[T]` can not outlive `element`)?  If so, IMHO, the explicit lifetime parameter for the trait definition is necessary `fn find_k_closest(&'t self, element: &'t T, k: usize) -> &[T]`, or the return value will have the same lifetime with `&self` due to the lifetime elision rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lifetime issues stem from the bound `&'a T: Add<Output = T>`. This says that `&T` implements `Add` **but only** when the lifetime is exactly `&'a T`.
What you most likely want is `for<'a> &'a T: Add<Output = T>` which specifies that `&T` implements `Add` for **any** lifetime that you choose. (1)

With this change, you sample code compiles without needing to specify any more lifetimes. [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=00933507edddcafe8b736fd206fddfb1).

```
trait Sample<T> {
    fn sample(&self, element: &T, k: usize) -> &[T];
}

impl<A, T> Sample<T> for A
where
    A: AsRef<[T]>,
    for<'a> &'a T: std::ops::Add<Output = T>,
{
    fn sample(&self, element: &T, k: usize) -> &[T] {
        let array = self.as_ref();
        let doubled = element + element;
        &array[0..0]
    }
}
```

---

(1) Strictly speaking, this is a more restrictive bound but I struggle to see a situation where the first one is fulfilled but not the second one.